# How to insert a animation in pickerInput .dropdown-menu.open?

Tags: r, shiny

I have this code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  pickerInput(
    inputId = "countryid1",
    label = "Select:",
    choices = c("Brazil", "Argentina", "Colombia", "Paraguay", "Bolivia", "Trinidad and Tobago"),
    selected = "Paraguay"
  )

)

server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I would like to know if it is possible to apply a `slideDown` (or `fadeInDown`) effect to the opening when I click on the input, that is, to apply a smoothed opening effect in `.dropdown-menu.open`, like this:

```
dropdown(
  "Your contents goes here ! You can pass several elements",
  circle = TRUE, status = "danger", icon = icon("gear"), width = "300px",
  animate = animateOptions(enter = "fadeInDown", exit = "fadeOutUp", duration = 1)
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also do this using only CSS animations. Namely `@keyframes` rule which specifies the animation code.

So the code would look like this

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  tags$head(tags$style("
    @keyframes slideDown {
      0% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateY(-20px);
      }
      100% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateY(0);
      }
    }
  /* Change the slide down animation time if needed  */
    .dropdown-menu.open {
      animation: slideDown 0.5s;
    }
  ")),
  
  pickerInput(
    inputId = "coutryid1",
    label = "Select:",
    choices = c("Brazil", "Argentina", "Colombia", "Paraguay", "Bolivia", "Trinidad and Tobago"),
    selected = "Paraguay"
  )
  
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Maybe this could also be of help: https://community.rstudio.com/t/how-to-create-a-glowing-or-flickering-actionbutton/42564

Answer (score 1):

[Shiny](https://github.com/dreamRs/shinyapps) and [ShinyWidgets](https://shinyapps.dreamrs.fr/shinyWidgets/) do not provide built-in functionalities specifically for animating `pickerInput` directly... you might consider using CSS animations or JavaScript libraries such as jQuery to complement i, like a [jQuery slideDown](https://api.jquery.com/slidedown/).

You need to add a custom JavaScript snippet to your `ui.R`:

```
tags$head(tags$script('
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("body").on("click", "#coutryid1", function() {
        $(".dropdown-menu").hide();
        $(".dropdown-menu").slideDown(400); // 400ms duration
      });
    });
'))
```

And add this snippet to your `fluidPage` section of `ui.R`:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  tags$head(tags$script('
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $("body").on("click", "#coutryid1", function() {
          $(".dropdown-menu").hide();
          $(".dropdown-menu").slideDown(400);
        });
      });
  ')),
  
  pickerInput(
    inputId = "coutryid1",
    label = "Select:",
    choices = c("Brazil", "Argentina", "Colombia", "Paraguay", "Bolivia", "Trinidad and Tobago"),
    selected = "Paraguay"
  )

)

server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The JavaScript code listens for a click event on the picker input with the id `#coutryid1`. When clicked, it hides the `.dropdown-menu` and then performs a `slideDown` animation over 400 milliseconds.

This example is directly targeting all `.dropdown-menu` elements, so it may interfere with other dropdown menus in your application. To make it more specific, you can customize the jQuery selectors.